# displaying backgammon board in android

Tags: android

I have a beginner question in android. I wanna create a backgammon game. I found images of board online and converted it to different dpi using online tools. Now when I decode it using decodeResource and display it in canvas it's very small. and when I scale it it has very bad quality.I tried all solutions including using matrix for scaling and different paint options. I think the problem is with the image itself. it's 72*72 by default. should I make it larger and then put it into dpi folders?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Put your high quality image(for example 960dp x 720dp) at drawable folder.And rebuild your project. That link maybe helpful about screen size [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) If you want to use high quality images for your app's UI,then read link which is on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

72*72 is very small. You should better make an image in 1920*1080 and put it into the `drawable` folder so it's not depneding on the size of the screen. You can always scale it down. Maybe make a smaller picture and put it in `drawable-small` to save ram on smaller devices, since bitmaps are pretty large.